# Using %. in printf

Tags: c++, c, printf

I've come across this line of code in `C++`. I'm not sure if I understand the syntax. Two variables are passed to `printf`, but only one number is displayed.

```
  printf("Value of bar is: [%.*s]\n", tok->len, tok->ptr);
```

Comment: Not an issue, but `printf` is really C, and it should not be used in C++.

Comment: @StefanoSanfilippo what do you use if you're a fan of C++ but not of <iostream>.

Comment: @Brandin: Boost Format.

Answer (score 7):

The format string

```
%.*s
```

consumes two arguments. The first specifies the precision, and the second is the value to be printed.

So suppose that `tok->len` has the value `3`. Then the code in your question is equivalent to:

```
printf("Value of bar is: [%.3s]\n", tok->ptr);
```

Read more about this from a good source of documentation, for instance: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf

As for what precision means in this context, the documentation source above says:

> Precision specifies the maximum number of bytes to be written.

Which is a slightly sloppy way to write it. It should say characters rather than bytes.

Comment: Funnily the "maximum number of bytes" is the wording used by N1570. It seems important to use "bytes" here because that means that the conversion specifier `sl` behaves in a very odd way.

Answer (score 3):

From the printf man-page under the paragraph `The flag characters`:

> The precision
>
> An optional precision, **in the form of a period ('.')** followed by an
>   optional decimal digit string. **Instead of a decimal digit string one
>   may write "*"** or "*m$" (for some decimal integer m) to specify that
>   the precision is given in the next argument, or in the m-th argument,
>   respectively, which must be of type int. If the precision is given as
>   just '.', or the precision is negative, the precision is taken to be
>   zero. This gives the minimum number of digits to appear for d, i, o,
>   u, x, and X conversions, the number of digits to appear after the
>   radix character for a, A, e, E, f, and F conversions, the maximum
>   number of significant digits for g and G conversions, or **the maximum
>   number of characters to be printed from a string for s** and S
>   conversions.

Emphasis mine.

In your case `%.*s` means the next argument indicates the precision which is to be interpreted as the maximum amount of characters of the following string argument to be printed.

Answer (score 2):

> .*  => The precision is not specified in the format string, but as an additional integer value argument preceding the argument that has to be formatted.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/